# Bootstrap Carousel showing all images at once when i use ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to add a carousel to my Bootstrap 3 website. But, All images are showing at once. I've reference from here [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h). Any suggestion please?

```
<div class="container" ng-show="hasImages">
    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="$index" class="$index  == 0 ? 'active' : ''"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <div class="$index  == 0 ? 'item active' : 'item'">
                <img bn-lazy-src="{{image.fullPath}}" title="{{image.description}}" alt="missing" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>{{image.name}}</h3>
                    <p>{{image.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any problem with this? `class="$index  == 0 ? 'active' : ''"`

Note: I'm using `bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.css` of version 3.3.5 and `jquery.min.js` of version 1.11.3.

**EDIT 1**: I also tried this(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel), Still i am facing same problem. All images are showing at once.

```
<div style="height: 305px">
    <uib-carousel interval="5000" no-wrap="false">
        <uib-slide ng-repeat="subCategorySlideShowImage in subCategorySlideShowImages" active="subCategorySlideShowImage.active">
            <img ng-src="{{subCategorySlideShowImage.fullPath}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                <p>{{subCategorySlideShowImage.text}}</p>
            </div>
        </uib-slide>
    </uib-carousel>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend using angular-ui bootstrap: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel

Comment: that also showing all images in single slide

Comment: can you make an jsfiddle?

Comment: @BettySt, please see my code in edit1 . thanks

Comment: @BettySt, I copied same code ( angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) to my project. the example code shows images all at a time.

Comment: @BettySt, Thanks for suggesting carousel. I got the solution and working fine now. problem is i'm using older version of some vendor scripts and which are causing circular dependency errors. FYI (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845522/bootstrap-carousel-showing-all-images-at-once-with-error-when-i-use-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-class dynamically set CSS classes based on the value of $index and set the class as required.

```
<div class="container" ng-show="hasImages">
    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="$index" ng-class="{'active': $index == 0}"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <div class="item" ng-class="{'active': $index == 0}">
                <img bn-lazy-src="{{image.fullPath}}" title="{{image.description}}" alt="missing" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>{{image.name}}</h3>
                    <p>{{image.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```