# Bootstrap Carousel showing all images at once with error when i use ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, carousel

I'm trying to add a carousel(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) to my Bootstrap 3 website. But, All images are showing at once with the error.

When i create a sample project with carousel(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) code it is working fine.

My module looks like below

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute', 'angularFileUpload', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar']);
```

And, for carousel requires below.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

So when i add above 2 into my project

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar']);
```

i am getting below error.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngAnimate%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.16%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngAnimate%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A26264%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A450%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A26264%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A260%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A26264%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A262%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A26264%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A1%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A26264%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A280)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A26264%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A32%253A445)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A26264%252Fscripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A18%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:26264%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:26264%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:33:332%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:26264%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:7:280)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:26264%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:32:445)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:26264%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:33:18%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:26264%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:7:280)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:26264%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:32:445

**EDIT**: After referring below

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
```

I am getting below error.

```
Line: 4442
Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- cfpLoadingBar <- $http <- authService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/cdep?p0=%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20cfpLoadingBar%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20authService
```

Comment: Do you really need angular for this? If you don't, I suggest you to use [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel). The only thing you need to do is adding `bootstrap.js` to the end of the document  `<body>`: `<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`. You might also need jQuery: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Put the jQuery script before bootstrap's. Then just copy and paste the sample code from [Boostrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

Comment: I initially used this one only. I faced same problem. Look at here my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637458/bootstrap-carousel-showing-all-images-at-once-when-i-use-ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stacktrace, angular didn't found the module `ngAnimate`. You probably forgot to link angular-animate script from your *index.html* page.

**index.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. after doing this , i am getting below circular dependency error. Please see EDIT section in my question. "Line: 4442
Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- cfpLoadingBar <- $http <- authService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/cdep?p0=%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20cfpLoadingBar%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20authService"

Comment: Looks like a problem with `'angular-loading-bar'` module. Can you remove the inclusion of the module and the eventual usages of it, to narrow down problems with ui-bootstrap carousel component?

Comment: Superb!... After removing 'angular-loading-bar' the carousel(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) working fine. I am using "angular-loading-bar v0.3.0  * https://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar"

Comment: Great! :) Looks like you're fine with angular. Best of luck!

Comment: @VirtuaCreative, Hold on.. Please I want 'angular-loading-bar' back which i've removed. What should i do?

Comment: First be sure to work with latest version of *angular-loading-bar*, as there was a circular dependency bug once, that has been corrected. If the problem still persists with latest version, that might come from the usage of it, but that's near impossible to tell without seeing code. You could then open a new thread with code, and ideally a plunker reproducing the problem.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos, After upgrading "angular-loading-bar v0.3.0" to latest version i.e)"angular-loading-bar v0.8.0" working perfect :). thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it! ;)